when i debug on my phone, the program can't access my music file
as discussed is there a way to access my music, notepad files while debugging from mobile.
I have tried adding it on the deploy tab, tried putting it in every folder in the project.
I use the media player to run it. It works just fine on my laptop but once i debug it, it says file doesn't exist.
Like I said, I placed it everywhere.
